# Updated: How do I plot letters of varying fonts in straight-line using the word cloud function in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, matplotlib, word-cloud

I am able to generate a word cloud using a dictionary selected from a dataframe (fresh) containing over 30k dictionaries in a single column (aa_comp). [image]

**Current Code:**

```
def Peptide_ICE(x):
    word_could_dict = fresh["aa_comp"][x]
    wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 1500, height = 500,prefer_horizontal=1,relative_scaling=1,
                      background_color='white',contour_width=10,contour_color="black" ).generate_from_frequencies(word_could_dict)
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
```

**Current Output of Function:**
[image: Output of Peptide_ICE]

**Expected Output:**
I would like it if the Letter were arranged in a straight line. Something like this but letters in place of the line, so I can modify the x-axis ticks with custom labels.

[image]

code to generated figure above:

```
temp=fresh.loc[fresh['gene'] == "HV404"]
test_dict = temp["aa_comp"][1]
x=list(test_dict.keys())
y=list(test_dict.values())
plt.plot(x,y, color='g')
```

Side question:
Originally, I wanted to plot these letters using matplotlib so that the height of the letter represented the value of each key either by the number shown or as the frequency of values for that dictionary. I can only think to use the addtext function and use a loop to determine the position of the each letter along the x-axis while determining a normalized font size with the value of each key. Am I far off on this? Is there a more 'pythonic' way?